# Calling method from .ashx -> response.write file

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, handler

In my .aspx:

```
public static void DoStuff(XmlDocument doc)
    {

    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;

        string xmlString = doc.InnerXml;

        string fileName = "ExportedForm.xml";

        response.StatusCode = 200;

        response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        response.AddHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
       // response.AddHeader("Content-Length", _Buffer.Length.ToString());

        response.ContentType = "application-download";
        response.Write(xmlString);
}
```

in my handler.ashx:

```
private void GenerateXml()
    {

        var JsonXmlData = HttpContext.Current.Request["objectToSend"];

        XmlDocument doc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(JsonXmlData);

        SystemAuditView.DoStuff(doc); //systemauditview is the .aspx
    }
```

If i call the `DoStuff` method from a click event it works. But when i call it from code behind, nothing happens. I suppose i somehow need to trigger a postback? Or whats the problem here? Thanks

Comment: could you give us code example of how you are calling it from click event and how you are calling it from code behind (in what method)?

Comment: @RăzvanPanda `SystemAuditView.DoStuff(doc);` from code beind. By click is a standard click event on an asp:button

Comment: Please edit your answer adding the code you use for the asp:button and the code you use in the buttons OnClick handler. On what event do you call `SystemAuditView.DoStuff(doc);` from code behind?

Comment: Using breakpoints, are you sure that the GenerateXml() function is being called, and the DoStuff() function is not being called?  You should be able to debug through GenerateXml() and see it calling DoStuff() - or more likely, throwing some sort of exception which is halting execution before the call to DoStuff() is reached.

Comment: @mikemanne I get to the end without exceptions... Dont you think i need to do a postback in order to refresh the headers etc?

Comment: I'm pretty confused here: you say every line of GenerateXml gets executed.  One of those lines is SystemAuditView.DoStuff().  However, if you breakpoint DoStuff() it doesn't get called.  If you step-into DoStuff in the debugger, where does it go?  Do you have 2 SystemAuditView classes (in different namespaces)?  There must be something odd happening: if GenerateXml calls DoStuff, then DoStuff must be getting called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating object for  SystemAuditView and then try to access DoStuff method.

Since DoStuff is a common method you should put this code in App_Code folder.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1291538.aspx

Comment: The problem is the difference between calling `DoStuff()` from code VS calling `DoStuff(object sender, eventargs e)` from a button. Only the buttonclick works.

Answer (score 0):

without knowing your page or namespace or class names to figure out which one is SystemAuditView, I would say you missed a step in "SystemAuditView.DoStuff()"

For instance, to call a method with the full name, you have to code: Page.namespace.class.method() to call it.

Or if you don't want to do that, you need to link the pages by inheritance or using.